# classloader.getResourceAsStream doesnt seem to load csv files

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am not sure if this is an IDE problem or java issue. 
Looks like csv files are not being loaded. If I refactor the file name  to test.xml, it gets loaded.

I have this code

```
       InputStream is_csv = getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.csv"); // is_csv is null

       InputStream is_xml = getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.xml"); // success
```

Not sure if its intellij  problem?

Comment: Is test.csv within the classpath?

Comment: I would guess so.. If I rename the same file to test.xml, it seems to pick it up.

Comment: may you have another test.xml in your classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh Got it..  @Luis  u r right..  I had to explicitly add to include csv files in my gradle.

```
test {
    java {
        srcDir 'test'
    }
    resources {
        srcDir 'test'
        include '**/*.xml','**/*.csv'
    }
}
```